# What is the logic behind this fstring in python?

Tags: python, binary

From this question: [Converting an integer to signed 2's complement binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274885/converting-an-integer-to-signed-2s-complement-binary-string)

we have this code:

```
def f(n):
    nbits = n.bit_length() + 1
    return f"{n & ((1 << nbits) - 1):0{nbits}b}"
```

I'm looking for some explanation/reference reading on the f string. In particular, what is the purpose of the `:`, the `0{...}` syntax and the `b`?

Comment: Have you read a tutorial on Python formatting? It explains how everything after `:` works.

Comment: I don't know about the logic behind this f-string, but I know for sure the takeaway from it: packing everything into an f-string one-liner creates an incomprehensible mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` separates the value to be printed from the format specification.

In a format specification, the last character specifies the type of formatting; in this case, `b` means binary. A number before that specifies the field with; in this case it's the value of the `nbits` variable (nested `{expression}` are expanded and used as part of the format specification). And a leading zero before the field width means to padd with zeroes.

So this prints `(1 << nbits) - 1` in binary in a field that's `nbits` wide with leading zeroes.

The leading zeroes in the specification don't seem relevant, because the value being printed will be `nbits` 1's -- there won't be any need for padding.